# How do I set Netbeans to use another browser as default in HTML5 project

Tags: html, netbeans

How do I set Netbeans to use another browser as default for a new HTML5 project.

The default seem to always be "Chrome with Netbean Connector".

I do not have chrome installed and would like this default set to FireFox.
This seems to be a separate setting to the default browser in the options.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options - General Tab - Web Browser
and choose your desired browser

Comment: I'm afraid not. That works for things like Javadocs. It has no effect on the default for HTML projects.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible. But I would think this is easy enough to change after the project is created, through the browser icon in the main toolbar.